# how unity can read data from Matlab socket

Tags: matlab, sockets, unity-game-engine

i want to do some simulation in unity. for my project i want to use Matlab as processing layer. so i want to use socket for communications.

**here Matlab is server and this is the code:**

```
clc
clear all
tcpipServer = tcpip('0.0.0.0',55000,'NetworkRole','Server');
while(1)
    b=1
data = membrane(1);
b=2
s = whos('data');
b=3
set(tcpipServer,'OutputBufferSize',s.bytes);
b=4
fopen(tcpipServer);
b=5
fwrite(tcpipServer,'hi');
fclose(tcpipServer);
d=6
end
```

i use 1,2,.. for showing the process

**i use this code in unity**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System;
using System.IO;


public class Socket : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization

    internal Boolean socketReady = false;
    TcpClient mySocket;
    NetworkStream theStream;
    StreamWriter theWriter;
    StreamReader theReader;
    String Host = "localhost";
    Int32 Port = 55000;


    void Start () {
        setupSocket ();
        Debug.Log ("socket is set up");
        Debug.Log (readSocket()+" is the message");
        closeSocket ();
        Debug.Log ("Socket is closed");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    public void setupSocket() {
        try {
            mySocket = new TcpClient(Host, Port);
            theStream = mySocket.GetStream();
            theWriter = new StreamWriter(theStream);
            theReader = new StreamReader(theStream);
            socketReady = true;
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Debug.Log("Socket error: " + e);
        }
    }

    public String readSocket() {
        if (!socketReady)
            return "";
        if (theStream.DataAvailable)
            return theReader.ReadLine();
        return "";
    }


    public void closeSocket() {
        if (!socketReady)
            return;
        theWriter.Close();
        theReader.Close();
        mySocket.Close();
        socketReady = false;
    }
}
```

at first i start Matlab then i play unity. the result is, the connection is done properly but i can not read the data Matlab send

**this is what i get in Matlab**

```
b =

     1


b =

     2


b =

     3


b =

     4


b =

     5


d =

     6


b =

     1


b =

     2


b =

     3


b =

     4
```

**and finally this is what i get in unity**

```
socket is set up

is the message

Socket is closed
```

**the expected result is**

```
socket is set up

hi is the message

Socket is closed
```

i dont know how to read data and how to implement it.

thank you

Comment: Don't you have the server/client mixed up? Based on [the documentation](http://www.mathworks.com/help/instrument/using-tcpip-server-sockets.html) if you want the `tcpip` object to write data to a socket it needs to be a client and not a server.

Comment: you are right. but it works by tow Matlab sessions correctly. now i send data  from unity to Matlab and i can read that. the next challenge is doing it vice versa  . thank you @Suever

Answer (score 0):

this is the simplest and complete solution. 
in this solution each of matlab or unity can be used as server or client.

**first, Matlab as server and unity as client**

**matlab code**

```
clc
clear all
tcpipServer = tcpip('0.0.0.0',55000,'NetworkRole','Server');
while(1)
data = membrane(1);
fopen(tcpipServer);
rawData = fread(tcpipServer,14,'char');
for i=1:14
   rawwData(i)= char(rawData(i));
end
fclose(tcpipServer);
end
```

**Unity C# code**

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System;
using System.IO;


public class Socket : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization

    internal Boolean socketReady = false;
    TcpClient mySocket;
    NetworkStream theStream;
    StreamWriter theWriter;
    StreamReader theReader;
    String Host = "localhost";
    Int32 Port = 55000;


    void Start () {


        setupSocket ();
        Debug.Log ("socket is set up");
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    public void setupSocket() {
        try {

            mySocket = new TcpClient(Host, Port);
            theStream = mySocket.GetStream();
            theWriter = new StreamWriter(theStream);
            socketReady = true;
            writeSocket("yah!! it works");
            Debug.Log ("socket is sent");

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            Debug.Log("Socket error: " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

**now vice versa, unity as server and  Matlab as client**

**Unity C# code**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Linq;
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Text;


public class readSocket : MonoBehaviour {

    // Use this for initialization
    TcpListener listener;
    String msg;


    void Start () {
        listener=new TcpListener (55001);
        listener.Start ();
        print ("is listening");
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        if (!listener.Pending ())
        {
        } 
        else 
        {
            print ("socket comes");
            TcpClient client = listener.AcceptTcpClient ();
            NetworkStream ns = client.GetStream ();
            StreamReader reader = new StreamReader (ns);
            msg = reader.ReadToEnd();
            print (msg);

        }
    }
}
```

**Matlab code**

```
clc
clear all
tcpipClient = tcpip('127.0.0.1',55001,'NetworkRole','Client');
set(tcpipClient,'Timeout',30);
fopen(tcpipClient);
a='yah!! we could make it';
fwrite(tcpipClient,a);
fclose(tcpipClient);
```

in each implementation the server should runs first before the client otherwise you will get the bellow error

> Connection refused:in Matlab or remote machine actively refuse the connection in unity